# Reading a CSV file using Python 2

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm running Python 2.7. I'm very new to Python.  I'm trying to read a CSV file (the values are separated by spaces) and separate the values inside based on the header above the coordinates. The format of the file isn't what I'm used to and I'm having trouble getting the values to read correctly. Even if I could get them to read correctly, I don't understand how to put them in a list.

Here is what the CSV file looks like:

```
# image name
1.png
# probe locations
100 100
200 100
100 200
300 300

# another image name
2.png
100 200
200 100
300 300
135 322

# end
```

Here's the code I am playing with:

```
class CommentedFile:
    def __init__(self, f, commentstring="#"):
        self.f = f
        self.commentstring = commentstring
    def next(self):
        line = self.f.next()
        while line.startswith(self.commentstring):
            line = self.f.next()
        return line
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

#I did this in order to ignore the comments in the CSV file

tsv_file = csv.reader(CommentedFile(open("test.exp", "rb")),
                  delimiter=' ')


for row in tsv_file:
    if row != int:
        next(tsv_file)
    if row:
        print row
```

the code prints out:

```
['100', '100']
['100', '200']
['100', '200']
['300', '300']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the path", line 57, in <module>
next(tsv_file)
StopIteration
```

So I'm trying to get the program to separate the coordinates based on the header and then put them into separate lists. Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's not *really* a CSV file, so it's probably not appropriate to use `csv.reader`. What's the desired output you want from the example input file?

Comment: I don't understand the line `if row != int:` ???

Comment: I eventually want to use the output from the reader/parser as coordinates for a graphic I am drawing. So a list, I think, with the x and y coordinates together the way they are in the output now. What should I use instead of csv.reader?

Comment: Sylvain -- I was trying to get it to check whether the row had numbers or letters in it, but I know that didn't work...

Comment: You want to accept any of the answers? Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: @user2479054 You should accept one of the answers if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It has a `DataFrame` object which can hold your data and allow you manipulate in an intuitive way. It also has a `read_csv` function which takes out a lot of the hassle when dealing with csv files.

for example:

```
import pandas as pd

#reads your csv file in and returns a DataFrame object as metioned above. 
df = pd.read_csv("your_csv.csv", sep=' ', names=['co_a','co_b'], header=None, skiprows=2)

#extracts your discordant to separate lists
list1 = df.co_a.to_list()
list2 = df.co_b.to_list()
```

you can use `df` or `df.head()` to see your dataframe and how your data is managed.  It's also worth mentioning that `df.co_a` is a `Series` object, think super list / dict, and you can probably do your analysis or manipulation right from there.

Also if you show me how the comments are in the `csv` file, I can show you how to ignore them with `read_csv`.

I know you were looking for an answer with the `csv module` but this is a much more advanced tool and might help you out in the long run.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you!! The CSV file looks *exactly* like it does in the question I asked. The comments follow hashtags (#). The CSV file doesn't have headers over the coordinates. Is there any way I can sort them by their column number? Or do I need headers? I can't really change the format of the CSV file.

Comment: column number is fine but it might be worth it to add simple names to the columns, I'll update my answer.

Comment: also, you might want to separate those two png lists into separate files. Both will not import into the dataframe correctly. If you remove every thing but the numbers, it will great with the code above.

Comment: Also since your new to python, its worth mentioning [IPython](http://ipython.org/) to easily manipulate this interactively, with out having to code compile run repeat. Specifically, check out the IPython notebook.

Comment: How do you get it to ignore the lines that begin with '#'?

Comment: you can use the `skiprows` argument in `pd.read_csv()` to manually skip them. I'll update my answer with that included. `skiprows` is indexed at 0 so you n-1 for the number of rows to skip. Also you will still need separate the files into two separate ones.

Comment: Hey, if my answer solved you problem, please click the 'check mark' next to it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked well for me actually. I don't know why you're getting the traceback.

tmp.csv

```
# image name
1.png
# probe locations
100 100
200 100
100 200
300 300

# another image name
2.png
100 200
200 100
300 300
135 322

# end
```

tmp.py

```
import csv

class CommentedFile:
    def __init__(self, f, commentstring="#"):
        self.f = f
        self.commentstring = commentstring
    def next(self):
        line = self.f.next()
        while line.startswith(self.commentstring):
            line = self.f.next()
        return line
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

#I did this in order to ignore the comments in the CSV file

tsv_file = csv.reader(CommentedFile(open("tmp.csv", "rb")),
                  delimiter=' ')


for row in tsv_file:
    if row != int:
        next(tsv_file)
    if row:
        print row
```

Shell output

```
tmp$python tmp.py 
['1.png']
['200', '100']
['300', '300']
['2.png']
['200', '100']
['135', '322']
tmp$uname -mprsv
Darwin 12.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386
tmp$python --version
Python 2.7.2
```